# Force download through js or query

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to force a download through JS or Javascript i-e the web page should not open the file in new tab in the browser but to pop up to let the user to choose eith "save as" or open with ???

Comment: Duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727144/browser-download-file-prompt-using-javascript

Comment: It is indeed. Good example of a useful duplicate, because the question title is worded fairly differently, even though it’s talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can not force that behavior from JavaScript, the HTTP Headers need to be set on the server side:

```
Content-disposition=attachment; filename=some.file.name
```

The way you can solve the problem is to let your AJAX method redirect the user to the URL of the PDF:

```
location.replace('path/to.pdf');
```

(The above HTTP headers must be set for the PDF)

---

**Update**

At the time of this answer, it wasn't possible. Now it is, scroll down to see [the other answer saying so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18330145/342852).

Comment: It's now possible with the [download](http://caniuse.com/#search=download) attribute.

Comment: @mpen yes, and there's an answer that says so. At the time of the question, it wasn't available

Comment: Yup. Not saying you need to change your answer, but it appears at the top and it's accepted, so I'm just letting people know that are too lazy to scroll further :-)

Comment: @mpen Since Chrome 65 it is not possible anymore for cross-origin hrefs. So if you want to create `<a href="https://i.imgur.com/IskAzqA.jpg" download>` on a domain other than imgur.com it will not work as intended. Deprecations and removals announcement here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/chrome-65-deprecations#block_cross-origin_wzxhzdk5a_download

Comment: No, neither the header, nor any other approach, forces the download. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: `download` attribute doesn't works for all media, specially for jpg/png files.

Answer (score 63):

With the advent of HTML5 you could just use the new property download in the anchor tag.

The code will look something like

```
<a download="name_of_downloaded_file" href="path/to/the/download/file"> Clicking on this link will force download the file</a>
```

It works on firefox and chrome latest version. Should I mention that I didn't check it in IE? :P

Edited the download attribute after comment from sstur

---

https://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: It's worth noting that you can specify a value for the download attribute and that will become the default filename for the download.

Comment: This indeed is the more progressive solution, but as of Nov/2013 has no support in IE or on most mobile devices. (Source : http://caniuse.com/#feat=download )

Comment: It doesn't work with Opera or IE, however this I still like this solution myself.

Comment: +1 to this more modern solution, but main remains valid until this one is implemented by all major browsers

Comment: Just implemented this after chasing PHP delivery timeouts for ... too long; and this got me out of the water in minutes. In everything but #MicrosoftInternetExplorer11 - still... as of 8/7/14. #Microsoft's terrible track record and miserable acceptable of the community around them aside - cheers to what I'm calling my new method of delivering downloads. Thank you.

Comment: As a [security feature](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676619), the download value that you specify will be ignored when the content is on a different hostname with the origins limited with headers like `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`.

Comment: The question is about forcing a pdf file to download without clicking anything. Like when some page is opened or a form is filled pdf is downloaded after thank you message.

Comment: This `download` attribute does not do what you seem to think it does.

Comment: Well, browsers will prevent you from enable downloading of files in different sites or under different ports, so quite a limited feature....

Answer (score 32):

dynamic create link and click it with download attribute for force download as file:

```
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href = this.props.download_url;
anchor.target = '_blank';
anchor.download = this.props.file_name;
anchor.click();
```

Take a notice that i didn't even added it to DOM, so it's fast.

P.S `download` attribute won't work with IE. But it will just open link in new tab.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: And click() doesn't work for many browsers too, or only for buttons : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Comment: What browsers? Old default android? I never had a ticket about this not working and this answer is several years old already. Make a test, show what is not working.

Comment: I can’t test with Edge and IE but last verstion of Firefox is not compatible with click() for a but only for buttons. Check the MDN link I just set before, in the bottom, special note for Gecko and it’s the same under safari 6 and chrome 20 (sure, old browsers)

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible and thanks God it isn't. Otherwise I leave you to the imagination of what kind of files could be stored on your computer when you visit a web site without you knowing it.

As @Paul D. White pointed out in the comments section if you want to open the file inline (inside the browser) with the default program associated with it you could have the server send the Content-Disposition HTTP header. For example:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=foo.pdf
```

Comment: Correct: you can only do it on the server-side, because it’s done by setting an HTTP response header (specifically `content-disposition: attachment`). Once the page is open in the client, the HTTP response has, by definition, already been processed.

Comment: The asker clearly says that he wants to use it with a dialog in stead of opening a new tab, so it isn't exactly what you are replying to?

Comment: @gnur, correct. I will update my answer to include @Paul D. White excellent proposal.

Comment: Currently i have a button on the page to download pdf..... What it does is invokes a ajax function which uses a back end PHP file to store the PDF on disk.Then i want to simply force download that PDF in the ajax success method .....

Comment: @user418232, I am afraid this is impossible. You CANNOT write to the client computer using javascript.

Comment: This answer is not precisely correct. More importantly, it doesn't address the question. Clearly the OP is not asking for direct access to the filesystem, because s/he specifically mentions the "save as" dialog.

Comment: "*Otherwise I leave you to the imagination of what kind of files could be stored on your computer when you visit a web site without you knowing it.*" Behond the almighty power of HTML5 (Chrome/Safari/iOS only): http://filldisk.com/

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible with JQuery/JavaScript only.

You will need a server side script which returns you the file with a `Content-Type` (HTTP Header) which will force the browser to download your requested file. An possible value for `Content-Type` would be `application/force-download`.

Comment: But even such a header will not force a download, depending on how the user has set the optional locally on his browser.