# How to get binary data from server using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, binary-data

I'm trying to download binary data using a Web API Controller, using [JQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

The code I tried is:

```
$.get("../api/Download/Report?Id=" + selectedItem.Id);
```

which transforms into an HTTP GET with this URL when I debug the running app:

```
http://localhost:12150/api/Download/Report?Id=2515
```

The browser shows 200 as result, receiving the binary data, but **it does not open it nor offers to download the file.** If I copy and paste the URL in the address bar and press 'Enter', it works.

Any suggestions or alternatives that allow relative paths?

Comment: Reading JQuery.get() documentation, it has an optional dataType parameter, but only seems to accept xml, json, script, or html

Comment: I guess the problem is server side. Can you provide us the Content-Type header? This will tell the browser what to do with the content. Plus, I would use $.ajax in that case...

Comment: If possible , can post data string response and type of data expected ; e.g., `image`, `text`, other ? Thanks

Comment: For the record, since the question was answered already, the type of data expected is application/octet-stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using  ajax for these kinds of things. If you want to force the user to download the response, that could get messy. Open a new tab/window instead; in most browsers it'll close itself anyway, and the user won't even notice that it was open! :) If you know your URLs on-load you could simply make an anchor tag with the `target="_blank"`-attribute. I.e.:

```
<a href="http://localhost:12150/api/Download/Report?Id=<?=$reportID?>" target="_blank">Download report</a>
```

(Well, you know basic HTML, but you get the idea)

If you want/need to do it with JS, go with a simple `window.open()`:

```
window.open("../api/Download/Report?Id=" + selectedItem.Id,'_blank');
```

**Disclaimer**: I don't know if that relative URL will actually work in `window.open()`. If it doesn't just fiddle around with constructing the URL via PHP first:

```
$reportURL = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/api/Download/Report?Id=";
```

and then, in your JS, just echo it:

```
window.open("<?=$reportURL?>" + selectedItem.Id,'_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

using `$.get` just puts the returned request data into an object you can handle in the callback. what you need to do is just have your api return the download url, then tell the browser to download it,

how to do this is explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5192980/1994767