# Downloading files with Ember app

Tags: ember.js

I have Ember App (built with Ember-CLI). On the backend I have Rails application which handles requests. Lets say that my API has following routes:

`/model` — returns list of models

`/model/1` — returns model

`/model/1/download` — returns file

How can I force Ember app to start file download (using `/download` path) and how can I construct link for file download from within Ember app?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just return the URL path for the download in your model for "/model/1". Then you can easily create links in your handlebars templates like so:

`<a href="{{model.download}}" target="_blank">Download File</a>`

Comment: If the file to download comes from Ember's back-end, I don't think it can work just like this. This will just open a new window displaying the Ember app with a route corresponding to the file URI, that may match nothing.

Answer (score 3):

1. If you're going to hit the endpoint and return the file contents, I believe you'll need to set the Content Disposition header. More details here: [Force download through js or query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192917/force-download-through-js-or-query)

`Content-disposition=attachment; filename=some.file.name`

2. If you are linking to the file directly, you could use the HTML5 `download` attribute;

`<a href="{{model.download}}" download>Download File</a>`

Comment: The __download__ attribute is not very well supported: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this, the html download attribute has 96% browser support now so Yuri's comment is no longer valid.

Comment: I agree with you @BrandenSilva. Support is strong across all current browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do any of these manually, keep it simple and use [ember-cli-file-saver](https://github.com/cogniteev/ember-cli-file-saver)!

```
// models/invoice.js
export default Model.extend({
  invoiceNumber: attr('number'),

  download: memberAction({ path: 'download', type: 'GET', ajaxOptions: { arraybuffer: true } })
});
```

```
// in a component
invoiceModel
  .download()
  .then((pdfContent) => this.saveFileAs('invoice.pdf', pdfContent, 'application/pdf'));
```