# How do I download a file (instead of opening it) with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

There is a way to download a file (instead of opening it) with HTML:

```
<a href="./images/myimage.png" download="myimage.png">Download</a>
```

What I am looking for is a way to do this with JavaScript. What I have is an AJAX call to retrieve a URL for an image:

```
function followUpFunction(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
        var status = (xmlHttp.status == 200) ? "good" : "bad";
        var returnedImageURL = xmlHttp.responseText;
        window.open(returnedImageURL);
        return;                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                     
}
```

You can see that way I'm downloading it now is by using JavaScript's `window.open` function.

The way it works now, the browser gives a pop-up window warning, which people don't like or don't notice, this ends up with many people not getting their download. I would prefer the image just download immediately like it does with my HTML snippet above. Also, I don't want the current window replaced or written over, I want it to remain visible just as it is.

So, is there a way I can do this with JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on browser support [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) is an option

Comment: @t.niese I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: @PatrickBarr I don't want to use external libraries.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37673039/1960455) to the linked question does not use jQuery.

Comment: @t.niese You are correct, I saw "js or query" and my mind smooshed them together to make "jquery". That solution worked perfectly, thank you! I had thought about doing it that way, but I didn't know how it would get clicked. I had no idea there is a "click" method; now I do. Thanks again. Do you want to post an answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Comment: @Brian it is already answered in the linked question so there is no need to create a new answer that would not provide any additional information.

Comment: @t.niese Gotcha ... thanks again.