# Download wont download with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

So, I have this code, and the download won't download this variable. Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Extension Maker</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <h1>Extension maker for chrome</h1>
    <input id="name" size="22" placeholder="Extension name">
    <br>
    <input id="vers" size="22" placeholder="Version">
    <br>
    <textarea id="desc" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
    <br><br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="popup">Popup <input id="popup-html" placeholder="Popup html">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="urlo">Change contents of single page <input id="page-cont" placeholder="Page HTML">
    <select id="select">
    <option value="newtab">New Tab Page</option>
    <option value="bookmarks">Bookmarks Page</option>
    <option value="history">History Page</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="js">Run JavaScript <input id="js" placeholder="JS">
    <br><br><br>
    <button onclick="downloadAll()" id="downloadbutton">Download</button>
    </form>
    <script>
    
        
        function download(filename, text) {
        alert("download script working");
        var element = document.createElement('a');
        element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
        element.setAttribute('download', filename);
    
        element.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    
        element.click();
    
        document.body.removeChild(element);
    };
        function downloadAll() {
        
        alert("downloadall works!");
        var first = document.getElementById("popup").checked;
        var second = document.getElementById("urlo").checked;
        var third = document.getElementById("js").checked;
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var vers = document.getElementById("vers").value;
        var desc = document.getElementById("desc").value;
        var pophtml = document.getElementById("popup-html").value;
        var manifeststart = "{     'name': " + name + ",     'version': " + vers + ",     'description': " + desc + ",               'manifest_version': 2   ";
        if(first === true){
        var manifest = manifeststart + "'default_popup': 'popup.html',       'default_icon': {         '16': 'images/get_started16.png'       }     },}";
        var text = document.getElementById("popup-html").value;
        var filename = "popup.html";
        
        download(filename, text);
        };
        if(second === true){
        var select = var text = document.getElementById("select").value;
        var manifest = manifest + "'chrome_url_overrides' : { ' " + select + "': 'myPage.html' }";
        var text = document.getElementById("page-cont").value;
        var filename = "myPage.html";
        
        download(filename, text);
        };
        if(third === true){
        var manifest = manifest + "'background': {'scripts': ['background.js'],'persistent': false },";
        var text = document.getElementById("js").value;
        var filename = "background.js";
        
        download(filename, text);
        };
        
        var text = manifest;
        var filename = "manifest.json";
        
        download(filename, text);
    };
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It adds json depending on the checked boxes. It just doesn't want to download the manifest.json. Also, when it downloads the json, is the json valid?

Comment: What's happening instead of the download? Did you try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192917/force-download-through-js-or-query/18330145#18330145 ?

Comment: @Capricorn one download downloads. the other doesnt. multiple downloads enabled

Answer (score 0):

Valid json should be surround with "" not with '',
you also had duplicated id on you JS elements
Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Extension Maker</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <h1>Extension maker for chrome</h1>
      <input id="name" size="22" placeholder="Extension name" />
      <br />
      <input id="vers" size="22" placeholder="Version" />
      <br />
      <textarea id="desc" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
      <br /><br /><br />
      <input type="checkbox" id="popup" />Popup
      <input id="popup-html" placeholder="Popup html" />
      <br />
      <input type="checkbox" id="urlo" />Change contents of single page
      <input id="page-cont" placeholder="Page HTML" />
      <select id="select">
        <option value="newtab">New Tab Page</option>
        <option value="bookmarks">Bookmarks Page</option>
        <option value="history">History Page</option>
      </select>
      <br />
      <input type="checkbox" id="js" />Run JavaScript
      <input id="js-code" placeholder="JS" /> <br /><br /><br />
      <button onclick="downloadAll()" id="downloadbutton">Download</button>
    </form>
    <script>
      function download(filename, text) {
        // alert("download script working");
        var element = document.createElement("a");
        element.setAttribute(
          "href",
          "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(text)
        );
        element.setAttribute("download", filename);

        element.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        element.click();

        document.body.removeChild(element);
      }
      function downloadAll() {
        // alert("downloadall works!");
        var first = document.getElementById("popup").checked;
        var second = document.getElementById("urlo").checked;
        var third = document.getElementById("js").checked;
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var vers = document.getElementById("vers").value;
        var desc = document.getElementById("desc").value;
        var pophtml = document.getElementById("popup-html").value;

        var manifeststart =
          '{"name": "' + name + '","version":"' + vers + '","description":"' + desc + '","manifest_version": 2,';

        if (first === true) {
          var manifest =
            manifeststart +
            '"default_popup": "popup.html", "default_icon": {"16": "images/get_started16.png"}';
          var text = document.getElementById("popup-html").value;
          var filename = "popup.html";

          download(filename, text);
        }

        if (second === true) {
          var select = (text = document.getElementById("select").value);
          var manifest =
            manifest +
            ',"chrome_url_overrides" : {"' +
            select +
            '":"myPage.html"},';
          var text = document.getElementById("page-cont").value;
          var filename = "myPage.html";

          download(filename, text);
        }

        if (third === true) {
          var manifest =
            manifest +
            '"background": {"scripts": ["background.js"],"persistent": false }}';
          var text = document.getElementById("js-code").value;
          var filename = "background.js";
          alert(text);
          download(filename, text);
        }

        var text = manifest;
        var filename = "manifest.json";

        download(filename, text);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```