# audio file download using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to download multiple files from s3 in queue. 
But the problem occurring is the audio files are getting streamed in browser player in-spite of getting downloaded.

Note: when i'm providing local path of audios then the download function is working exactly as intended ,in all browsers but with s3 path the audio gets streamed/played in browser.

Here is what I have tried -

**sending array of .mp3 paths -**

```
$.each(jsonarray, function (key, value) {
       download_files([{download: value}]);
});
```

**download function-**

```
function download_files(files) {
    function download_next(i) {
        if (i >= files.length) {
            return;
        }
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = files[i].download;
        a.target = '_parent';
        var nameArray = a.href.split('/');
        var filename = nameArray[nameArray.length-1].replace(/%20/g, " ");
        if ('download' in a) {
            a.download = filename;
        }
        (document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(a);
        if (a.click) {
            a.click(); 
        } else {
            $(a).click();
        }
        a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
        setTimeout(function () {
            download_next(i + 1);
        }, 500);
    }
    download_next(0);
}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>`  try this, this should work

Comment: @AkhilAravind tried the same but the issue remains same.

Comment: Check this fork: https://codepen.io/jelmerdemaat/pen/brjKG it might help you.

Comment: Go through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192917/force-download-through-js-or-query/18330145

Answer (score 0):

do not include .mp3 extension file name eg. `<a href="/path/audioname" download>`