# want to download file by jquery form submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery

when user submit the form, a png file will download automatically without url change. how it's possible in jquery any idea? I am trying....

```
<script>
 jQuery( "#gform_3" ).submit(function( event ) {
 window.open('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/172905/test.pdf', '_blink', 'download');
  event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192917/force-download-through-js-or-query

Comment: have some questions, will this file which is going to download, is a static file or a random file, which will be downloadable after submit button task is finished, or this file will be a sample file, which is tatically avaialable ?

Comment: static pdf or png file will download