# Download a File Using Just JavaScript

Tags: javascript

To programmatically trigger a file, located on the server, using JavaScript, here's what I'm currently doing:

### HTML

```
<a id="downloadPDF" href="/my.pdf" download style="display: none;">Download PDF</a>
```

### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('downloadPDF').click();
</script>
```

It works, but it feels rather "hackish" to me. Is there a better, more straightforward way of doing it without using HTML and triggering clicks?

Important: No libraries or data URIs. The file should download *not* open.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force download through js or query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192917/force-download-through-js-or-query)

Comment: @A.Meshu seems OP is already well aware of the information in that post

Comment: _'It works, but it feels rather "hackish"'_... welcome to web application programming

Comment: Well, you can alter your function to dynamically create hidden <a> tag, click it and delete...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my implementation, which I like more since it's cleaner:

```
document.querySelector( 'body' ).insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', '<a id="downloadPDF" href="/my.pdf" download style="display: none;"></a>' );

document.getElementById( 'downloadPDF' ).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just extension to method, that you have provided in your question. Differences is that this function do all work in background.

```js
// DL function
const download = function(file) {
  // Create a tag
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  // Set href
  a.href = file;
  // Set file name
  a.download = file.substr(file.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  // Append tag to body
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  // Click it
  a.click();
  // Remove
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}

// Do download
download('https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/02/zip_2MB.zip');
```